# makeindex doesn't work

Tags: amsmath, indexing, amssymb

I have a file `statuts.tex`, and I would like to add indexes. Somebody says indexes belong to `ams` packages, so I did the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\makeindex{terms}
\begin{document}
body
\index{terms}{abc}
% \printindex{terms}{Index of Terms}
\end{document}
```

a part of my `makefile`:

```
statuts.pdf: statuts.tex
    latex statuts.tex && \
    makeindex statuts.idx && \
    latex statuts.tex && \
    makeindex statuts.idx && \
    latex statuts.tex && \
    dvips statuts.dvi -o statuts.ps && \
    ps2pdf statuts.ps statuts.pdf
```

However, I have got an error in the very beginning:

```
Writing index file statuts.idx

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \makeindex{t
                erms}
?
```

I don't want to use the package `makeidx`, because I have already used `ams` packages in my document and there is a conflict. In addition, I don't think the package `amsmidx` is necessary...

Could anyone help?

Comment: `makeidx` *is* necessary, and `\makeindedx` does not take an argument. `makeidx` provides the missing `\printindex` that `article` does not.

Comment: indexes are supported only in ams *document classes*, not in ams *packages*.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `imakeidx` for all my `index`ing needs. It is so easy.

Save the following as `myfile.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=terms,title=Index of terms,columns=1]
\begin{document}
  body
  \index[terms]{abc}
  \printindex[terms]
\end{document}
```

Then compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile`. (or `latex` → `dvips` → `ps2pdf`) That is all. No need of compiling with `makeindex` by yourself.

[image]

There is a nice blog by the author himself [here](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/dont-forget-to-run-makeindex/). Now guess the author yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a package by Barbara Beeton, released as part of the AMS facilities for LaTeX, that introduces a syntax like the one you want and is called `amsmidx`, but it works *only* with the AMS classes which support `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmidx}
\makeindex{terms}
\begin{document}
body
\index{terms}{abc}
\Printindex{terms}{Index of Terms}
\end{document}
```

Note `\Printindex` and not `\printindex`.

Patching it for making it work with `article` would be possible. But the best, in my opinion, is to use `imakeidx`.

Comment: `imakeidx` can replace `amsmidx` even with most instances using ams document classes, but if the class redefines the running footer to use anything but "plain" style, the `[original]{imakeidx}` option must be used, and the indexes processed separately before rerunning latex.  when `[original]` is used, the last page of a multi-column index isn't balanced.  (if the problem with how `imakeidx` fails to honor a document-specific running foot design could be solved, `amsmidx` could be retired.  `imakeidx` is better; it just didn't exist when `amsmidx` was needed and created.)