# MiKTeX - makeindex not working anymore

Tags: miktex, makeindex

I don't know what happend, but my MWE [mwe_NormOrdner.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8DpN9H9EfbPQV9fYTVDMS1hWGM) from this question: [LaTeX: Unbalance imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354152/latex-unbalance-imakeidx) does not work anymore (straight downloaded and ran it - *no dice*)!

I've reinstalled MiKTeX for the 3rd time now and still nothing. My `*.idx` files are created but remain empty (no content, no error)! That used to work before... some (MiKTeX|package) update?!

I don't know what do try anymore ...  my indices are not printed anymore.

Comment: Funny enough; this one works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223385/36508

Comment: The M in MWE means _minimal_ so by definition it does not mean a zip file on an external site. Unless you plan to keep that link working _forever_ then the question should be understandable without following links. Also what does "not work" mean? There will be an error message in the makeindex or tex logs if it failed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: 1. How can I upload a zip to stackexchange (the zip file contains all the files necessary to reproduce my document)? 2. My .idx files remain _empty_ - nothing in them. They get created but without any content. 3. I'll try to keep that zip file right there for as long as possible.

Comment: surely you should be able, starting from that document to make a simple one-file example to post here, that is the intention of asking for a "MWE",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morewrites.sty in miktex is a day older than the one in texlive 2017 and seems to be the source of the problem. Make a bug report for miktex that it should update. As a workaround you can try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__morewrites_close_all:
  {
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g__morewrites_write_prop
      { \__morewrites_tex_immediate:w \__morewrites_tex_closeout:w ##2 \scan_stop: }
    \prop_gclear:N \g__morewrites_write_prop
    \prop_map_function:NN \g__morewrites_write_file_prop
      \__morewrites_closeout_now:nn
    \prop_gclear:N \g__morewrites_write_file_prop
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[noautomatic,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=terms,title=Index,columns=1]
\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\begin{document}
  body
  \index[terms]{abcdef}
  \printindex[terms]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. I was just about to post my find, that it had something to do with `\usepackage{morewrites}`. Your workaround works like a charme - nothing else expected coming from you!